# How to create something like menu from android?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I want to create something like menu in android in Windows Phone. I found that there is something what would be good but I can't even find anywhere how it's named. I marked it red on screenshoot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are referring to is the `ApplicationBar` or "AppBar".

You can read more about it in the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx

For examples of how to program with it see http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/06/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-6-application-bar/

Note that this is a native Windows Phone element and does not correspond directly to the Android menu and users of each platform would likely expect them to behave differently on each platform.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I found it very hard to find information about even default components in Windows Phone. In Android everything seems to be a little bit easier. :)